# How to navigate to deeply nested screen composable from the Activity's onCreate in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-architecture-navigation

Suppose I have a notification, that when clicked, launches my app's activity. It's a notification about a message, in a conversation, and so it launches the activity passing the `conversationId` as an argument. When the activity is launched by that intent from the notification, it should open `MessagesScreen`, which is a deeply nested screen in the app, passing to it `conversationId`.

What is the best way to do this in Compose? In the good old Fragments or Activities you just navigated straight to it, but with Compose is a little trickier. The path to the `MessagesScreen` is as follows:

`SplashScreen (checks for authentication) -> HomeScreen (if authenticated) -> ConversationScreen -> MessagesScreen`

I can't just navigate straight to `MessagesScreen` by having the compose's `NavController` be stored in the Activity, since I need to go through `SplashScreen` to check for authentication. Also, I don't know the Compose's implication of navigating to a deeply nested component from the Activity's `onCreate()`.

What I currently do is have a field in my global `ViewModel` called `notificationConversationId`, that is set on my Activity's `onCreate` if it was passed by the notification's intent:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       
    val conversationId = intent.getStringExtra("conversation_id") ?: ""
    globalViewModel.notificationConversationId = conversationId

    // ...
```

Then, in a `LaunchedEffect` in my `HomeScreen` I observe this field, and if it is not empty, I navigate to the `MessagesScreen`, and set it to an empty string, so the `LaunchedEffect` is not executed again.

```
val conversationId = globalViewModel.notificationConversationid
LaunchedEffect(conversationId) {
    if (conversationId.isNotEmpty()) {
        val path = getMessagespath(conversationId = conversationId)
        globalViewModel.notificationConversationId = ""
        navController.navigate(path)
    }
}
```

It works, but it is horrendous. Is there a better way to accomplish this in Compose? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is horrendous about it?

Comment: Are you using `androidx.navigation:navigation-compose` for navigating?

Comment: @hahmraro Did you got any update regarding this? How you have done this?